# Pipe data chunks as a Response to a clients terminal

Tags: node.js, express, pipe, response

so my question is on Node js piping. So my backend looks like this -- there is a simple route, the route calls function and passes to it a file path for an executable type file. This file is then run with the `childProcess.spawn` and there is a `data` output that I can `console.log`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
etc...

const runExecutable = (executableFile) => {
   const runFile = childProcess.spawn(executableFile);

   runFile.stdout.on('data', function(data){
       console.log("DATA", data);
   })

   runFile.on('exit', function(code, signal){
       [some code here]
   })
} 

app.get('/example', (req, res) => {
   var file = "./testFile.exe";
   runExecutable(file);
})
```

The question I have is how can I pipe this output of `data`/a.k.a chunks in real time to the client, it's important for them to get the data as it comes out and not for me to write it to a file and send them the whole thing. One more thing to note, the client is accessing my route through a curl `curl 123.45.678.901/example` in their terminal and I want to pipe the `data` to their terminal.

On reading around, I know that for example the request module does a `request.get(url).pipe(res) /[Express res]` and so I'm wondering if this is similar to what I might need to be doing.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: Any stream can be piped - [readable.pipe(destination[, options])](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) - `childProcess.spawn(executableFile)` is not a stream, but once the file starts being executed it does emit a `"data"` event which is another way of saying there is a stream being emitted from the running of the file. So if you are looking at these chunks of `"data"` coming out - like I am - like this:

```
runFile.stdout.on('data', function(data){
      console.log("DATA", data);
  })
```

then that's the stream that you use and that's the where you attach the `pipe`

Node documentation basically says - to the stream attach `.pipe` and then just send it to it's destination. Since I wanted to send these chunks of data to my client I also had to pass `res` around, so my code now looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
etc...

const runExecutable = (executableFile, res) => {
   const runFile = childProcess.spawn(executableFile);

   runFile.stdout.on('data', function(data){
       console.log("DATA", data);
   }).pipe(res)

   runFile.on('exit', function(code, signal){
       [some code here]
   })
} 

app.get('/example', (req, res) => {
   var file = "./testFile.exe";
   runExecutable(file, res);
})
```

and it works! I hope this is helpful to others - Thanks for the help Lee!